# infinite loop when using free() in while loop

Tags: c, malloc

I am writing a code which should read 512B from file into a buffer and then check if it found 3 specific bytes and if true break from while loop. 
I am early in my code and I am testing each sub part when I found that when I am using free() to release buffer memory from heap I get stuck in infinite loop. But my test doesn't include buffer at all and when I remove free() then test passes and I get out of loop.But I think that I have to free buffer in the loop so at each pass I can load new block. My code is here:

```
// input: read in a card.raw file
// output: 50 jpg images


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* search(char *s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure correct usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage --> recover card.raw\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // try to open a file for reading
    char *infile = argv[1];
    FILE *fp = fopen(infile,"r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open file: %s\n", infile);
    }

    // read a 512B block process it and
    char magicNum[3] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};
    char testNum[3] = {0xfa, 0xd8, 0xff};
    char *extractMagicNum = testNum;
    while (extractMagicNum[0] != magicNum[0] || extractMagicNum[1] != magicNum[1] || extractMagicNum[1] != magicNum[1])
    {
        char *buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
        fread(buffer, sizeof(char),512, fp);
        // now search buffer for 0xff and when found check next two bytes if magic number break
        printf("I am in while loop\n");
        extractMagicNum = search(buffer);
        // used for checking if return value is right
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("%i.Element is %i\n",i,*(extractMagicNum + i));
        }

        free(buffer);
    }

    printf("End...\n");


    // close infile
    fclose(fp);

}

// use bisection search to find 0xff and next two bytes
char* search(char *s)
{
    char magic[3] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};
    char *p = magic;
    // just not to get unused error
    s++;
    s--;
    printf("I am in search \n");

    return p;  //return value should satisfie while condition
}
```

Comment: In your `search` function, the variable `p` is pointing to the first element of `magic`. And `magic` is a local variable which will go out of scope and cease to exist when the function returns. That will leave you with an invalid pointer, and [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: what you say is logical but when you comment out free(buffer) code works. Why does it work now?

Comment: Seemingly working is one of the possibilities of undefined behavior. It probably works when removing the `free` call because that call might clobber the memory where the pointer is pointing.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I will try instead of using local variable to put it on heap.

Comment: If the array is static and non-changing, consider marking it as such. If you make the array `static` then its life-time is for the whole program and it will always exist.

Comment: I think this is better solution because I don't know how would I free memory when I return from function

Comment: Note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition.

Comment: I know but just to be verbose I guess. Maybe it's better to keep it short though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable.  How you resolve that will depend on the required semantics.  In this case, declaring `magic` static will resolve the issue:

```
char* search(char *s)
{
    static char magic[3] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};
    char *p = magic;

    ...

    return p;  //return value should satisfie while condition
}
```

Though if the data referenced by `magic` and `s` should not change then the following might be preferred:

```
const char* search( const char* s )
{
    static const char magic[3] = {0xff, 0xd8, 0xff};
    const char* p = magic;

    ...

    return p;  
}
```

Another issue is that your while loop does not compare the third element.

```
while( extractMagicNum[0]va != magicNum[0] || 
       extractMagicNum[1] != magicNum[1] || 
       extractMagicNum[1] != magicNum[1] )   // << index should be 2 here perhaps?
```

Note also that a simpler method of suppressing unused variable warnings is to use self-assignment:  `s = s ;`.  The compiler will likely recognise the idiom and generate no code.

Regarding the `malloc`/`free`, while these are not the direct cause of your problem, it nontheless serves no purpose to thrash the heap by constantly allocating and freeing the buffer of invariant size.  Just allocate the buffer once, and reuse it:

```
char *buffer = malloc(512);

while( extractMagicNum[0] != magicNum[0] || 
       extractMagicNum[1] != magicNum[1] || 
       extractMagicNum[2] != magicNum[2] )
{

    ...
}

free(buffer);
```

You could further simplify the while condition thus:

```
while( memcmp( extractMagicNum, 
               magicNum, 
               sizeof(magicNum) ) !=0 )
```

Comment: Thanks for deeper explanation.